# Where to download a trained LDA model for Gensim?

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda

I want to use an LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) model for an NLP purpose. 
To train a such a model from Wikipedia corpus takes about 5 to 6 hours and wiki corpus is about 8GB. Check the [Tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation)

Rather than doing so, is there a place to download a built LDA model and use it directly with Gensim?